# Scala Collection filtering on multiple items

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, scala-collections, tail-recursion

I have the following recursive function to remove items from a list (**zooResidents: List[(String, Int)]**) that are contained in another list (**pets: List[String]**). It works, but is very slow. What is the *Scala* way of doing this?

```
val pets = List("cat", "dog")

val zooResidents = List(("cat", 4), ("lion", 2), ("tiger", 3), ("dog", 2) 

def removePets(zooResidents: List[(String, Int)], pets: List[String]): List[(String, Int)] =  {
  if (pets.isEmpty) zooResidents
  else removePets(zooResidents.filterNot(_._1.contains(pets.head)), pets.tail)
}

removePets(zooResidents, pets)      //> res2: List[(String, Int)] = List((lion,2), (tiger,3))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `List#contains` is linear as it has to scan the entire list, I would recommend you using a data-structure with constant-time lookup like `Set`

```
val petSet = pets.toSet
val filter = zooResidents.filterNot(element => petSet.contains(element._1))
```

Comment: Sleiman. Thanks that works! I am new to Scala, can you please help me understand how the above works?

Comment: This is simply invalid, returns `cat` and `dog`, you need to negate the condition.

Comment: Lukasz, yup I changed to filterNot. Then it does what I needed it to do.

Comment: Sorry guys, it's a "typo"

Comment: @SaqibAli We are just filtering the elements in the list, for-each element if the set contains the current element we don't add it to the result list.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would call scala way

```
@ zooResidents filterNot { case (resident, _) => pets contains resident } 
res6: List[(String, Int)] = List(("lion", 2), ("tiger", 3))
```

For better performance, `pets` should be a `Set`.

`filterNot` takes only those elements that do not fulfill the predicate, i.e. those for which the given function returns `false`. So we want to take all those elements for which `pets` does not contain first element of the tuple.

You can use pattern matching instead of regular function to destructure tuple as I did this

```
{ case (resident, _) => pets contains resident }
```

this is equvalent to

```
(residentTuple => pets.contains(residentTuple._1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val zooResidents = List(("cat", 4), ("lion", 2), ("tiger", 3), ("dog", 2)
val pets = List("cat", "dog")
```

*Try this one-liner:*

```
zooResidents.filter(x=>pets.toSet.contains(x._1)==false)

scala> zooResidents.filter(x=>pets.toSet.contains(x._1)==false)
res167: List[(String, Int)] = List((lion,2), (tiger,3))
```

pets changed to be a Set for performance.

This takes zooResidents List and checks for existence of each string in pets also and returns only those elements of zooResidents which are not in pets the `==false` will do this.

Comment: Please add an explanation.